# User Control For C++ CLI

Tags: c++-cli

sorry for my poor English, i want to use CLR user control for my application, i have found many c# sample code for user control, but I cannot find correct C++ CLI sample. I have tried many times, now I give up and trying to convert the code from c# to c++. The following is my code, and there are something wrong, could anyone help me how to fix? Many thanks.

Reference https://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_user_controls.html

```
c#
public delegate void SubmitClickedHandler();
[Category("Action")]
[Description("Fires when the Submit button is clicked.")]
public event SubmitClickedHandler SubmitClicked;

C++
delegate void SubmitClickedHandler();
[Category("Action"), Description("Event raised when clicking on an item")]
event SubmitClickedHandler ^ SubmitClicked;

c#
protected virtual void OnSubmitClicked()
{
    if (SubmitClicked != null) 
    {
        SubmitClicked();  // Notify Subscribers
    }
}

C++
private: virtual void OnSubmitClicked()
{
    if (SubmitClicked != nullptr) // <---ERROR
    {
        SubmitClicked();
    }
}

C#
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    OnSubmitClicked();
}

C++
private: System::Void BN_LOAD_CFG_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    OnSubmitClicked();
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is C# code, not C++/CLI code, the `protected` keyword is not used correctly.  You know how to do it since you got it right with the `private` keyword.  Ideally written on a line by itself, the ":" colon is required.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, I haves modified code and update, but there is a little bit wrong, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: That's more C#.  The nullptr test is not necessary in C++/CLI, unlike C# it supports the raise() accessor.  And illegal, it can only be used on a delegate and not an event.  So just write SubmitClicked() without the if-test.  Do favor [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-use-events-in-cpp-cli?view=vs-2017).